# Do API call when uninstallation process WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, uninstallation

I want to do api call when user do uninstall of the desktop app. I developed its installer using [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/). It is for Windows only. I also want to send MAC address, so we can track user who do uninstall. I searched over google, but i do not found any help related to uninstall process. If you have implemented this types of process before, Please help me.

Wix :
https://wixedit.github.io/
Version: v0.7.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The fairly obvious answer is to create a custom action, that is called with a condition of REMOVE="ALL", meaning that the product is being uninstalled. It's not clear from your post if you have researched that far, but that's the general approach you would take.

There are some other considerations you haven't mentioned: for example if the product is upgraded with a new version then the older product is being uninstalled, but it's part of an upgrade so I assume you would not want this to count as an uninstall (see UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE property - you'd add it to the condition on your uninstall custom action).

Comment: Phil, what do you think about the legal implications of sending the MAC on uninstall? I ask because I really don't know what to answer people who ask me. Some might argue that this borders on malware behavior? Would you need to update the license agreement? Personally I am against all Internet activity from setup internals - for now. In the future it will probably be mandatory to have an active Internet connection for some deployments (home users especially).

Comment: I don't know about Phil but I'm not a lawyer.  This guy says he is: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ip-mac-addresses-personal-information-eric-lambert/

Comment: Thanks PhilDW

I want a uninstaller to be wait until response of the API arived. Can you send me some reference link.

@Stein Asmul, Thank you for mentioning this points, but our terms of use and PP have a sentence, we do have rights.

Comment: @JK Patel Just wanted to mention it. I would also think such a reporting feature would be unreliable for a lot of reasons relating to missing Internet access due to silently running setup and impersonation issues (no Internet access for service accounts), missing runtime dependencies, proxy Internet access, security software interference for "unusual setup behavior", etc... One of my pet peeves is the danger of doing things in the setup that isn't possible to make reliable. You will have to code this very well and defensively to avoid it causing you unexpected problems.